# Confluent JDBC source Connector incremental starting row

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to use the Confluent's JDBC source connector to retrieve data from a SQL Server table into Kafka.

I want to use the incrementing mode to start retrieving data from the table **only from the moment the connector starts running**:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id_column_name
```

When I run this connector, it starts retrieving all the rows from the table, not the ones that are going to be inserted after that point in time. I've been checking the [connector configuration properties](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html) but I can't seem to find a configuration element for this situation.

The table doesn't contain any Timestamp values, so I can't use the properties `timestamp.initial` and `timestamp.column.name` properties. It includes a `Datetime` column however, but I think this is not useful in this case.

How can I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [query-based ingest](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#query-based-ingest) or [manually seed the offsets topic](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#starting-table-capture) with the appropriate value.

Source: [**Kafka Connect Deep Dive – JDBC Source Connector**](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#starting-table-capture) by [Robin Moffatt](https://www.confluent.io/blog/author/robin-moffatt)